# May I use this logic to get the Google Account email address (using Google+ API (People) )

Tags: c#, google-plus, google-oauth

when I use 「https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{userId}」to get the json of people profile,
I use the code below to get user's google account email(.NET)
but is there any guarantee that the user's google account is the first one of emails[] array?
I doubt if this is the right way to get a user's email.

```
        if (json.emails != null)
        {
            if (json.emails.Count != 0)
            {
                if (json.emails[0].type == "account")
                email = json.emails[0].value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What are you looking for the authenticated users email address, or the email address of someone else?

Comment: I just use the google oauth2 login in my website so i need to get the user's google email address that is verified . I'm not sure if i can get it from "emails[0].value" above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would use `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` as its the current authenticated user you are after.

If you read the documentation found at:  [People](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people)

```
Emails is a list with value and the type.  Type = account is what you are after.
```

The type of address. Possible values include, but are not limited to,
the following values:

- "account" - Google account email address.
- "home" - Home email address.
- "work" - Work email address.
- "other" - Other.

The list may contain more the one email address, but just scan though them looking for the one that is set to type = account.

**Note:** Scroll to the bottom of this page you can play with the response:  https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get

(Remember to authenticate it in the top of the "Try it!" form, also in the userId field just type me)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and i will use a loop to find the type of "account".